# django not retaining a filename

Tags: python, html, django

Chrome downloads the zip file as "download.zip", firefox downloads it as "IEtEk_sk.zip.part" and Internet explorer doesnt even prompt to save it, it tries to open the raw content in another window.
Why isnt the download being saved as "dbs_custom_library.zip" in all browsers or even downloading at all in IE?

html form

```
<form action="/django/builder/buildit/" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="val1" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="val2" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="thisispersian" checked/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

views.py

```
def zipit (file_paths):
  buffer= StringIO.StringIO()
  z= zipfile.ZipFile( buffer, "w" )
  for p in file_paths:
    if os.path.isdir(p):
      for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(p):
        for f in files:
          filename = os.path.join(dir, f)
          z.write(filename, arcname = filename[31:])
    else:
      z.write(p, arcname = p[31:])
  z.close()
  buffer.seek(0)
  return buffer.getvalue()

def persian (mylist):
  files = []
  if 'val1' in mylist:
    files.append('/home/dbs/public_html/download/Persian/Books/val1.html')
  if 'val2' in mylist:
    files.append('/home/dbs/public_html/download/Persian/Books/val2.html')
  return files

def main(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    mylist = request.POST.getlist('list')
    if 'thisispersian' in mylist:
      files = persian(mylist)
    zipped = zipit(files)
    zipped['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=dbs_custom_library.zip'
    return HttpResponse(zipped, mimetype="application/x-zip-compressed")
  else:
    return http.HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: The W3C document describing Content-Disposition (RFC 2616) seems to require double quotes around the filename.

Comment: I just changed the line of which you were referring to this `zipped['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="dbs_custom_library.zip"'` with the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're packaging a `HttpResponse` in a `HttpResponse`. Don't do that.

Comment: `zipit()` should probably `return buffer.getvalue()` instead

Comment: I am getting this error `'str' object does not support item assignment`